# React Failed to compile error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Hoping someone can help me with this issue I'm struggling with - seems to be a common issue with babel-loader, but I can't work it out.

I'm trying to add a new library [react-keyed-file-browser](https://github.com/uptick/react-keyed-file-browser) to an existing React project. When I attempt to import I'm receiving this compile error:

```
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/dnd-core/lib/reducers/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
type: action.type,
payload: {
    ...action.payload,
    prevTargetIds: get(state, 'dragOperation.targetIds', []),
},
```

I can't see anything in dnd-core that I shouldn't be able to load.

The import lives roughly here:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Select from 'react-select'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import config from '../../config'

import FileBrowser from 'react-keyed-file-browser'

// style import
import './style.scss'

class Documents extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
```

Here are some related dependencies from package.json:

```
"babel-core": "6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
"babel-jest": "20.0.3",
"babel-loader": "7.1.2",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
"babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-keyed-file-browser": "^1.9.0",
```

Here is the contents of babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-0", "react"],

  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],

  "env": {
    "build": {
      "optional": ["optimisation", "minification"]
    }
  }
}
```

And what I think is the relevant part of webpack.config:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
    enforce: 'pre',
    use: [
        {
            options: {
                formatter: eslintFormatter,
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),

            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
        },
    ],
    include: paths.appSrc,
},
{
    oneOf: [
        {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
        },
        // Process JS with Babel.
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
                cacheDirectory: true,
            },
        },
        // Css loader
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: cssLoader,
        },
        // Sass loader
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: cssLoader.concat([
              require.resolve('sass-loader'),
            ]),
        },
        {
            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

I can see this question asked elsewhere, but not answered. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your `babelrc` file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [["next/babel", { "preset-env": { targets: { node: true } } }]]
};
```

And modify your **webpack** config file for `url-loader`:

```
webpack(config, options) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: {
            limit: 100000
          }
        }
      });
      return config;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Would you be able to provide some more detail around these changes? Are you saying completely replace babelrc with your code? Do I need to upgrade my version of Babel to 7 to do this? As far as url-loader, are you just changing the extensions I have provided? Thanks for responding.

Comment: you need to add  ` "url-loader": "^2.2.0" ` and yes replace your whole babelrc with the above code.  "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",       "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",

Comment: Sorry, not able to resolve. I have updated libraries to what you recommended. .babelrc, I couldn't add your code as it expects JSON, so converted it to that .. but not sure what 'next/babel' is referring to?? Are you saying it's not possible to resolve the original issue with the versions I'm running? Can you tell me what you think is the actual issue?

Comment: Any thoughts @sidverma? Reckon it can be resolved with my current versions?